How to remove "customers in the last year" from Paypal business profile?
We are sending the business link to our customers, and it does not look right to show the "joined date" and "number of customers" info. How can highlighted info in green be removed from the business profile? Also, we cannot revert the business profile or make any changes there.
We are wondering what is the good use case for this page? We have an external system for invoice generation and add the paypal link for the payment. We do not generate invoice from paypal.


If you don't like the page..don't use it? Send a link to an about section of your own website.

Thank you Preston for the comments. We got a reply from PayPal, it is working as intended and those info cannot be removed as per their "social" policy. They suggested to use invoice or request payment feature instead.
